# Java count longest possible array

Tags: java, arrays, count

I'm doing a coin toss program, and am trying to determine the longest possible run of heads or tails that were tossed. I already have code for determining if toss is heads or tails, but now need to count longest possible run. Help! Here's my code for the basic program.

```
    public static void coin_toss(char [] toss)
    {
        int s = 0;
        try
        {
            for (s = 0; s <= toss.length; s++)
            {
                double flip;
                flip = (double)(Math.random());
                if (flip < 0.5)
                    toss[s] = 't';
                else
                    toss[s] = 'h';
            }//end of for loop to load array
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException errorMessage)
        {
            System.out.println("\nSubscript out of bounds");
            System.out.println("Subscript went past the limit of " + toss.length);
            System.out.println("Last value of subscript was --> " + s);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }//end of toss coin

    public static double percent_heads (char [] toss)
    {
        double percent_h;
        int heads = 0;
        for (int s = 0; s < toss.length; s++)
        {
            if (toss[s] == 'h')
            heads = heads + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("There were " + heads + " heads results");
        percent_h = (double)heads / toss.length;
        return (percent_h);
    }//end of heads percentage function

    public static double percent_tails (char [] toss)
    {
        double percent_t;
        int tails = 0;
        for (int s = 0; s < toss.length; s++)
        {
            if (toss[s] == 't')
            tails = tails + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("There were " + tails + " tails results");
        percent_t = (double)tails / toss.length;
        return (percent_t);
    }//end of tails percentage function

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int num_toss = 0;
        double heads, tails;
        double percent_t, percent_h;
        DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat ("#0.00%");

        System.out.print("How many tosses would you like? --> ");
        num_toss = GetInput.readLineInt();
        char [] toss = new char[num_toss];

        System.out.println("You chose " + toss.length + " tosses");
        coin_toss(toss);
        heads = percent_heads(toss);
        tails = percent_tails(toss);
        System.out.println("The percentage of heads was --> " + percent.format(heads));
        System.out.println("The percentage of tails was --> " + percent.format(tails));
        longest_toss(toss);
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println("\nProgram terminated at " + today);
        System.exit(0);
    }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

Comment: Using an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to determine when you've gone out of bounds of the array is really poor practice.  It's better to use toss.length so you'll know the actual length

Comment: longest_toss function ?

Comment: geek_guy: i didn't post my longest_toss function cuz it's crap right now!

Comment: Have you tried with Integer.MAX_VALUE as I have mentioned in answer below

Answer (score 1):

There is a method I came up with.

```
public static void longest_toss(char[] toss){
        int longestrun = 0;
        int curlongestrun = 0;
        char prevrun = toss[0];

         for (int s = 1; s < toss.length; s++)
         {
             if (toss[s] == prevrun) {
                 curlongestrun++;
             }else {
                 curlongestrun=0;
             }
             if(curlongestrun>longestrun){
                 longestrun = curlongestrun;
             }
             prevrun = toss[s];
         }
         System.out.println("Longest run is : " + longestrun + " Coin side : " + prevrun);
    }
```

Comment: note that there is a error in your coin_toss method. The for loop condition should be `s < toss.length`

Comment: @user2899341 please accept an answer if you find it satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

You can get maximum index of the array `toss[]` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8`

Here it is less by 8 because, in the source code of `java.util.ArrayList` class, it is clearly mentioned that, `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` provided you have sufficient memory to hold the content of array with this much data.

Answer (score -1):

```
int getLongestHeads(char [] toss){

int longestHeads = 0;

for(char c : toss)
{

if(longestHeads > 0 && c == 'h'){
longestHeads = longestHeads + 1;
}
else{
longestHeads = 0;
}


if(c == 'h' && longestHeads == 0) {
longestHeads = 1;
}

}

return longestHeads;
}
```

Comment: we are not supposed to count heads here we have to give number for longest continuous run either of head or tail...

Comment: @AurA the question says the longest run doest not specify the longest run among head and tails or for both , or is it ambiguous for only me . If it is as you say you can implement it the same way for tails and compare the highest longest run. I dont understand the reason for downvote.

Comment: This is not the correct solution for consecutive runs.. you need the store the last run char to ensure that it is consecutive in the next. See John's answer ... that is the correct solution